# Downvote, delete vote, upvote: confusion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-delete

Tonight, I've run into several answers with score 0, no recorded up or down votes, but recorded delete votes. So they get no delete link. But when I downvote, the delete link shows the pre-existing delete votes.

Example where I ran into this:

[How to subtract a query result from another query result in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380312/how-to-subtract-a-query-result-from-another-query-result-in-mysql/6380336#6380336)

Comment: I think your original wording of this post was clearer.

Comment: But wrong. I checked, and the didn't have a history of up and down votes adding up to zero, just a big fat 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a result of the new review system. Don't know if it's intentional or not.

When clicking "Delete-This is a link only answer" for a reviewed Low Quality Post it seems like that actually counts as a delete vote, even though I can normally only vote to delete answers with a negative score.

---

And even if it is a bug, 20k users can already downvote an answer to -1 and then immediately vote to delete it.

Comment: Yes, I do it all the time.

Comment: This is exactly correct.