# Will an upvote cancel my delete vote, or would it still be there if the question is downvoted again?

Tags: support, up-votes, vote-to-delete

I cast a delete vote for a question, after downvoting it to the minimum of -3 score. Later, someone upvoted the question and the delete link is gone, so I cannot see if others also voted for deletion.

Will my (and other users') delete vote reappear if someone downvotes that question again, or is it automatically cancelled?

I've seen [Downvote, delete vote, upvote: confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143067/downvote-delete-vote-upvote-confusion) but I am not so sure if it exactly described the same situation as explained above.

Comment: Is it visible in your votes tab?

Comment: @user400654 Yes, it is. But does that mean it will reappear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the later upvote will not remove your delete vote. The higher score only stops others from voting to delete, but does not remove already-existing delete votes.

As an example, [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325465/377214) still has one pending delete vote that someone cast while it had a negative score; it has a positive score now, but that delete vote is still there. (I can see it as the author of the post.)

> [image]

You can on occasion see such posts in the 10k tools (posts with pending delete votes that can't be voted for deletion anymore because their score isn't low enough anymore): such posts will appear grayed out in the *Delete votes* section, but they'll have their current count of delete votes listed.

The only scenario in which delete votes are actually *removed* is on questions, if they [get reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353613/377214): if it later gets closed again, it will have to start afresh on delete votes. Other than that, the vote score will not result in delete votes being removed.